# COM LocalServer between different users

Tags: session, com, local

I've built a COM LocalServer exe for communication, and a client and it seem to work only if the same user is running both of them.

If I run the server on one user, and then switch user and run the client on the same computer

CoCreateInstance returns that "Class is not registered".

How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: When you register the server, are you registering it in HKLM or HKCU?  My guess is you're registering it in HKCU.

Comment: The server is not registered, but it still works in the current user scope.

Comment: A server should be registered so that a client program can find it and start it.  I'm guessing you started your server yourself and got it terminated again when you switched user accounts.

Comment: I started the server, but when switching accounts I didn't logoff the server account - and the process kept existing.